# contacts in android

Tags: android

I want to get all phone contacts from device in android.i have used the following code.but the problem is it  takes more time to return the results.is there any solution?

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        int index=0;
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
        {
            phoneNames=new String[cur.getCount()];
            phoneNumbers=new String[cur.getCount()];
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
             name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));



        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {

             phoneNames[index]=name;
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null);


                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        phoneIndex++;
                        phoneNumbers[index] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        index++;
                    } 
                    pCur.close();

            }     
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean it takes a lot of time to execute this code?

Comment: You have n^3 complexity here with n^2 different database transactions. You can almost certainly do this all in a single database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the code i assume that what you want is a list of contacts with DISPLAY NAMES and their respective phone numbers.

If you are specifically looking for data related to phone numbers i suggest you query on 
android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup and fetch the results using a single cursor.
The following are the fields that you would be interested in:
DISPLAY_NAME
HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
NUMBER
TYPE

e.g

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
 resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
```

Further details please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html)

Please post your requirement if the assumptions are not true.

- Some of quick checks:

  1. Select only the required columns and    not all in the first query.
  2. Instead of using Integer.parseInt(cur.getString) use 
     cur.getInt()
  3. Use PhoneLookup whenever dealing with phone numbers ( the    number
     field    gives the raw phone  number
     instead of    the value stored    in
     the database    which can contain
     -,),( appended with   it)
  4. Avoid using Cursor within a cursor. Use the API's which includes
     joins already implemented in it like
     RawContactsEntity, PhoneLookup.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do complex database queries on the UI thread.  What are you trying to do with the results?  If you are displaying things in a list, use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) so that you only pull out what you need when you need it.